# What to use after a preposition, a noun or gerund

Tags: grammar, gerunds, nouns

Please consider the following sentences:

*It doesn't have any symptom of stay.

It doesn't have any symptom of staying.*

The *stay* in the first sentence is a noun and *staying* in the second is a gerund. Which one to use and if both are OK, what is the difference between them please?

Comment: Neither are natural English statements, and I'm not sure quite what you want to express here. One possibility that comes to mind is *It **shows no sign** of leaving* (whatever "it" is, it's here, and doesn't seem like it's about to go anywhere). I can't imagine a context where anyone would actually say *It shows no sign of **staying***, but syntactically that's perfectly ordinary. Something like *It doesn't look as if it's going to stay* might be better for that sense.

Comment: I would have to agree with the person who commented above. If I had to choose between the two sentences I would pick the one that has staying in it, but neither sentence really makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I've used Google's definitions of *stay* to provide the below.

Many words in English have different, but often related meanings depending on whether they are used as a verb or noun.  The gerund will use the verb's meaning.

> It doesn't have any symptom of a stay.

*Stay* as a noun means "period of staying somewhere" or "a curb or check (equivalent to stopgap or 'thing that blocks')."

> It doesn't have any symptom of staying.

Gerunds represent an instance of an activity, typically in progress.  *Stay* as a verb means "remaining in the same place, state, position", "living somewhere temporarily", or "stopping or delaying something."

You might be thinking that "a curb or check" for *stay* versus "stopping or delaying something" for *staying* mean the same thing.  Here's an attempt to explain the difference:

- a *stay* would be a thing or object that is preventing things from happening.  Properties of things include who is using it, what it is, and attributes like color, etc.
- while a *staying* would be an event where something was prevented from happening.  Properties of events include time/duration/progress, place, action, and involved parties/things.

Comment: +1, So if we conclude that "stay" means: *a period of staying somewhere*, and "staying" means: *remaining in the same place*, we can say that both have the same meaning but with a subtle difference. Agree?